# Pro Tools 9 LE automation gets erased

Tags: pro-tools, automation

I have a troubleshooting question.

I've been automating a 14 minute film with downward expansion and for some reason, the automation gets erased.  Anyone know why?

I go before a section turn it to off, run through, select settings and go back to the beginning of the section, put in write and go through.

Comment: @Syndicate Totally didn't take it that way. I completely forgot there are big differences in automation functionality and jumped the gun and answered with HD. I should have clarified.

Comment: It still remains a mystery for me because I was doing all the things that you had said.  For the record, I'm using PT 9 LE

Answer (score 2):

What automation mode were you in?

In your automation control window, was "Plug-in" or "Volume" write enabled?

What do you mean by "automating downward expansion"? This is usually set and forgotten about with a plug-in.

And what do you mean "turn it to off"?

If you mean you are setting the controls for the plug-in with the automation off, you MUST copy the automation settings before turning automation back on, because once it's reading automation again it switches back to whatever your track has written to it - i.e. if you don't copy the settings before you enable automation again, all your fiddling and work will be gone once it's snapped back to what was previously there.

Let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: All automation is enabled

I'm automating the floor and gate open.

I go through the section first to get the right settings with automation set to off.

I have been copying the controls before going back in.



Comment: Then do you make a selection and paste the automation into that selection with the automation enabled?

Comment: No i go to the beginning of the section, hit write, and then play and it writes to the section.  

I've noticed though going back through on multiple passes that the gate automation seems to dissappear on some of them.  I'm using Waves comp gate.

Comment: Hmm. I'd try writing selections. Or, make sure that parameter is enabled for automation, And if that fails, go to the Gate automation playlist you're trying to change and manually write it that way. I suspect that the parameter you are having trouble with isn't auto enabled though. Good luck!